# How to create perpendicular bisector

Tags: analytic-geometry

Say we have an `0XY` coordinates plane. We have coordinates of points `A(xa, ya)`, `B(xb, yb)` forming line. How to find points `C` and `D` forming new line so that its center would be in the middle of `AB` and its length would be some `N*K` float value:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Let $v$ be $\vec {AB}$ normalized and let $u=v^{\perp}=(-v_y,v_x)$. Then $C=E+\frac 12 NK u$ and $D=E-\frac 12 NK u$, where $E=\frac 12(A+B)$.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

1. Find the co-ordinates of E. [$E = (0.5(x_a + x_b), 0.5(y_a + y_b))$]
2. Find $m_{AB}$, the gradient of AB.
3. Find $m_{DC}$, the gradient of DC by m.M = –1.
4. Find θ, the angle of inclination of DC by $m_{DC} = tan θ$.
5. Find $X_c$ and $Y_c$ as shown.
6. Do simple additions to get the actual co-ordinates of C.
7. For D, do similar subtractions.